# How to set a margin between rows

Tags: html, css

I've this code structure

```css
.col_1_6 {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}

.col_1_4 {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}

.row-content {
    clear:both;
    padding-bottom: 105px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-content">
    <div class="col_1_4">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates aperiam sint nam ea rerum. Ullam dolor ratione repellat assumenda laboriosam rerum omnis expedita esse dolores totam reiciendis nihil voluptatem eos.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col_1_6">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates aperiam sint nam ea rerum. Ullam dolor ratione repellat assumenda laboriosam rerum omnis expedita esse dolores totam reiciendis nihil voluptatem eos.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row-content">
    <div class="col_1_4">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates aperiam sint nam ea rerum. Ullam dolor ratione repellat assumenda laboriosam rerum omnis expedita esse dolores totam reiciendis nihil voluptatem eos.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col_1_6">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates aperiam sint nam ea rerum. Ullam dolor ratione repellat assumenda laboriosam rerum omnis expedita esse dolores totam reiciendis nihil voluptatem eos.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to set a margin between `row-content` but I try to set a `padding-bottom: 105px`, it still does not work.

How can I set a clean margin between these rows ?

Comment: Please always make sure to provide https://jsfiddle.net demo URL for HTML related queries. This will help the community members to assist you much quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Add following code will solve your problem.

```
.row-content::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```css
.col_1_6 {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}

.col_1_4 {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}

.row-content {
    clear:both;
    padding-bottom: 105px;
}
.row-content::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-content">
    <div class="col_1_4">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates aperiam sint nam ea rerum. Ullam dolor ratione repellat assumenda laboriosam rerum omnis expedita esse dolores totam reiciendis nihil voluptatem eos.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col_1_6">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates aperiam sint nam ea rerum. Ullam dolor ratione repellat assumenda laboriosam rerum omnis expedita esse dolores totam reiciendis nihil voluptatem eos.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row-content">
    <div class="col_1_4">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates aperiam sint nam ea rerum. Ullam dolor ratione repellat assumenda laboriosam rerum omnis expedita esse dolores totam reiciendis nihil voluptatem eos.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col_1_6">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates aperiam sint nam ea rerum. Ullam dolor ratione repellat assumenda laboriosam rerum omnis expedita esse dolores totam reiciendis nihil voluptatem eos.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're running into a very common problem when floating elements in a container. The container will collapse to the height of the non-floated elements (in this case, there are none). One 'hack' that many people use is called the 'clearfix' hack, which is what Usman is referring to. Here is a quick article you should reference whenever you need to create a .clearfix class! Creating a class makes this solution reusable on more than just your .row-content elements. Apply the clearfix class to any container when you want it to keep its height despite its contents being floated.

http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Answer (score 0):

You dont need **`float:left`** for class - `.col_1_6`
Please remove the border from `row-content` latter.

You may also visit the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/r46wodz6/) @ JSFiddle.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
.col_1_6 {
    width: 70%;
}

.col_1_4 {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}

.row-content {
    clear:both;
    /*padding-bottom: 105px;*/
    border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row-content">
    <div class="col_1_4">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates aperiam sint nam ea rerum. Ullam dolor ratione repellat assumenda laboriosam rerum omnis expedita esse dolores totam reiciendis nihil voluptatem eos.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col_1_6">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates aperiam sint nam ea rerum. Ullam dolor ratione repellat assumenda laboriosam rerum omnis expedita esse dolores totam reiciendis nihil voluptatem eos.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row-content">
    <div class="col_1_4">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates aperiam sint nam ea rerum. Ullam dolor ratione repellat assumenda laboriosam rerum omnis expedita esse dolores totam reiciendis nihil voluptatem eos.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col_1_6">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates aperiam sint nam ea rerum. Ullam dolor ratione repellat assumenda laboriosam rerum omnis expedita esse dolores totam reiciendis nihil voluptatem eos.</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```